# Use of creating a package.json file in our Node project

Tags: npm

> Why do we create a package.json file using npm init and what is its use while uploading our project on git?

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json is the core of npm. In this file all of your dependencies and node packages are outlined. It's important to upload to you git repository so that anyone cloning your project will have the same dependencies and packages on the same version as the project was developed in. In addition, being able to startup a project with `npm start` and `npm install` makes everyone's life easier.